# Ubuntu или Debian, помогите выбрать

Tags: ubuntu, debian

Я планирую поднять веб сервер (php, apache, mysql), но возник вопрос, чтоже лучше поставить, Debian, которым уже год пользуюсь или Ubuntu, которая говорят еще стабильнее дебиана. Проект достаточно высоко нагружен, однако мощностей не так много даже скажем впритык. Еще я волнусь не станет ли Убунта есть больше ресурсов дебиана если я поставлю ее?

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu - дистрибутив, построенный на основе Debian, поэтому реальная техническая разница между ними невелика (особенно если сравниваются Debian Stable and Ubuntu LTS): пакеты, включаемые в дистрибутивы будут иметь разные версии, что обусловлено разными циклами выпуска. Серьезным отличием Ubuntu является платная поддержка от Canonical, но важно скорее для крупных хостеров, вроде Amazon.

Утверждение о том, что Ubuntu стабильнее (требовательнее к ресурсам) Debian, равно как и прямо противоположное, ни на чем не основано. Поэтому если Вы в течение года живете на Debian, то нет смысла тратить время и силы на переход на Ubuntu, Вы ничего не выиграете.

Answer (score 2):

Для новичков - UbuntuДля знающих людей - Debian

Для веб сервер посоветовал бы именно Debian или free-bsd

Answer (score 2):

Debian Squeeze. No comments.

Answer (score 1):

Если на сервер, то лучше Debian. Как-то  принято считать, что Debian более стабильная, хотя и более сложная в администрировании и пользовании и менее подходит для дескотопов.

Answer (score 1):

Естественно стабильный Дебиан, а не Убунта, которая и есть площадка для испытания нестабильного ПО для Дебиана! Тем более сервер на ОСи с порушенной системой распределения прав вообще что-то немыслимое!

Answer (score 1):

Псомотрите репозиторий backports в дебиане и убунту LTS и сделайте вывод -в убунту LTS поддержка фактически означает только устранение уязвимостей. Стабильности от убунту не ждите, её версии выходят по графику независимо от отлова ошибок. С выходом новой версии о старой практически забывают.

Answer (score 0):

Debian SqueezeИ какая разница новичок или нет? Администрирование все-равно в консоле(не рассматриваем те варианты, когда у народа на серваках гуи) да и конфиги одни и те же. да, дебиан несколько медленнее будет грузиться,Но в для дебиана можно применить how-to от убунты , а вот наоборот не всегда может получиться (было пару случаев, поэтому забил и работаю на серверах исключительно на дебиане) десктопные решения - убунту 100%

Answer (score 0):

**Ubuntu Server LTS**5 лет поддержки! Потом легко перейдёте на новый LTS и снова 5 лет - спокойствия и стабильности!

Answer (score 0):

я бы не сказал,что для десктопов нужно ставитть именно убунту,можно Дебиан,или Минт.Последний кстати говоря будет по надежнее и покрайне мере получше в некоторых аспектах,чем убунту та же.Да и софт как ни крути,что для одного дистра что для другого одинаков,идет с оф сайта убунтудебиан и остальных ,и что еще можно добавить.Дистр выбирайте именно тот который вам нужен,по вашим потребностям.=))вот что еще неLTS или LTS -это без разницы.ибо если полюбить какуюнибудь ОС и версию,то уже следующая вам некак непонравится и поставите ту ,что вам дороже,хоть если она и например убунту 7.04

Answer (score 0):

Мой совет, бери то что хорошо знаешь! Обе системы стабильны!